# How to start the Xfce Terminal always maximized in Xfce?

Tags: xfce, xfce4-terminal, maximize

I'd like to start the Xfce Terminal in Xfce always maximized. (Usually, I do that through the launcher in the panel.)

I've already done that [for Emacs by means of X resources](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/426914/4319); however, `xfce4-terminal` doesn't read X resources.

How to make it be always started maximized?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately, `xfce4-terminal` doesn't read X resources, so that there is no unified way to make such configuration for all X clients which are xfce4-terminals (even remote ones.)

[Start terminal maximized?](https://www.reddit.com/r/xfce/comments/5owiur/start_terminal_maximized/dcmteid/) has already been asked at reddit and answered; that's only a part of the complete correct answer:

> Change the `Exec` command in `/usr/share/applications/xfce4-terminal.desktop`.

There are two drawbacks with this answer:

1. `/usr/share/applications/` is not the place for customizations; it would be overwritten by distro package upgrades.
2. It doesn't affect the launcher for the terminal, which in its turn uses `exo-open --launch TerminalEmulator`. (This problem was pointed out in that thread at reddit.)

Solutions:

#### 1. The place for customizations

Per the advice by killermoehre in https://mail.xfce.org/pipermail/xfce/2015-April/034375.html:

> Never ever change files in `/usr` (except for `/usr/local`) directly. They will be overwritten on updates. If you want to make changes, copy them before into `~/.local/share/applications/` (create if necessary).

so, I've edited `/usr/share/applications/xfce4-terminal.desktop` and saved it to `~/.local/share/applications/xfce4-terminal.desktop`. The changed line looks like this:

```
Exec=xfce4-terminal --maximize
```

#### 2. Affecting the behavior of the launcher

By grepping through `~/.local` and `~/.config` after having configured a custom helper as the Terminal through the menu, I've found the other place that needs to be changed -- `~/.local/share/xfce4/helpers/custom-TerminalEmulator.desktop` (`--maximize` is present at two places):

```
[Desktop Entry]
NoDisplay=true
Version=1.0
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=X-XFCE-Helper
X-XFCE-Category=TerminalEmulator
X-XFCE-CommandsWithParameter=/usr/bin/xfce4-terminal --maximize -x "%s"
Icon=xfce4-terminal
Name=xfce4-terminal
X-XFCE-Commands=/usr/bin/xfce4-terminal --maximize
```

whereas I have the following `~/.config/xfce4/helpers.rc`:

```
WebBrowser=firefox
MailReader=thunderbird
FileManager=Thunar
TerminalEmulator=xfce4-terminal
```

Comment: If you use the keyboard shortcuts  like Ctrl+Alt+T and Super+T to launch the Terminal emulator, you will need to edit those too.
Mine both now look like this: exo-open --launch TerminalEmulator --maximize

Comment: I saved the files ~/.local/share/applications/xfce4-terminal.desktop ~/.local/share/xfce4/helpers/custom-TerminalEmulator.desktop and ~/.config/xfce4/helpers.rc, and it is not working to me

Comment: @iago Please tell us when you find out why.

Comment: How terribly complicated. I submitted https://gitlab.xfce.org/apps/xfce4-terminal/-/issues/306 to try to get them to fix it.

Comment: I found all I needed to do was
f=share/applications/xfce4-terminal.desktop;
mkdir -p ~/.local/$(dirname $f);
perl -pwle 's/^(Name|Exec)=.*Terminal$/$& --maximize/i;' /usr/$f > ~/.local/$f
and then moving the xfce Terminal icon to the highest place in the ChromeOS toolbar, after booting all I need to do is TAB TAB ENTER, and before long I am staring at a genuine maximized xfce Terminal!