# Difference between xfce4-terminal and exo-open --launch TerminalEmulator

Tags: terminal, xfce

I've come across these two and it seems to execute to the same terminal. Also if there is text for it somewhere, I would love to read it (I've found this: [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/426933/how-to-start-the-xfce-terminal-always-maximized-in-xfce) but doesn't exactly explain what the difference is, nor can I find why there are two).

Comment: Did you consult their respective manuals?

Answer (score 6):

The command `exo-open --launch TerminalEmulator` will launch the preferred terminal emulator, which may or may not be `xfce4-terminal`. The preferred applications are set in Settings Manager > Preferred Applications.